# Cypher slowly create relations with some type nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have one type of node and one type of relationship.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
load csv from 'http://host.int:8787/rel_import.csv' as line FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
match(c1)
with c1,line, trim(line[0]) as abs1, trim(line[1]) as abs2
match(c2)
where (c1.abs = abs1 and c2.abs = abs2) or (c1.abs = abs2 and c2.abs = abs1) 
create (c1)-[rel:relations{abs1:line[0], abs2:line[1], kind:line[2],personId:line[3], rel_k1:line[4], rel_k2:line[5],contact:line[6], id:line[7]}]->(c2)
```

So, it was fast.

I div one type node (now five types, old type deleted, summary count of entities not changed), and have problem with speed creating relationship.  structure of nodes not changed, indexes created for all types.

How do it right?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the where clause in your join is complex. I find complex where clauses on joins cause it to be really slow. Could you do: "where c1.abs <> c2.abs?"

Comment: I tried this, when rewrite query with explain and profiler.
It's faster, but very slower if compare with version where one type of node .

P.S. if it important: set contains 174.564 relations and 148.971 nodes. Loading when one type of node ~ 2-3 minutes. Loading when  five types, I spended one hour and kill docker container.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to do something like this:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
load csv from 'http://host.int:8787/rel_import.csv' as line FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
with line, trim(line[0]) as abs1, time(line[1] as abs2
match(c1{abs: abs1})
match(c2 {abs:abs2})
match c3 {abs: abs2})
match c4 {abs: abs1})
where c1.abs <> c2.abs and c3.abs <> c4.abs
create (c1)-[rel:relations{abs1:line[0], abs2:line[1], kind:line[2],personId:line[3], rel_k1:line[4], rel_k2:line[5],contact:line[6], id:line[7]}]->(c2)
create (c3)-[rel:relations{abs1:line[0], abs2:line[1], kind:line[2],personId:line[3], rel_k1:line[4], rel_k2:line[5],contact:line[6], id:line[7]}]->(c4)
```

If possible I'd break up the `match c1, c2` and the `match c3, c4` and run LOAD CSV twice, I find it's best when possible to do fewer steps within the LOAD CSV.

Comment: it slow too, was crated  4560 of relations per 10 minutes =(
for 174.564 of relations, it was ~6 hours